# What's the plural of "suéter"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, plurales, sustantivos, préstamo-lingüístico, vocabulario

What's the plural of "suéter"?

In Mexico, most of the times is called "sueters".

Is it "sueters" or "suéteres"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Word Magic](http://www.wordmagicsoft.com/dictionary/es-en/su%E9teres.php) and [Wiktionary](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/su%C3%A9ter) `suéteres` is the correct word.

This is a word borrowed from English word `sweater` and when the noun ends with `-r` you must form the plural with `-es`([Formación del plural en español](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formaci%C3%B3n_del_plural_en_espa%C3%B1ol))

> **Sustantivos y adjetivos terminados en -l, -r, -n, -d, -z, -j.** Si no
>   van precedidas de otra consonante, forman el plural con -es: dócil,
>   pl. dóciles; color, pl. colores; pan, pl. panes; césped, pl. céspedes;
>   cáliz, pl. cálices; reloj, pl. relojes. Los extranjerismos que
>   terminen en estas consonantes deben seguir esta misma regla: píxel,
>   pl. píxeles; máster, pl. másteres; pin, pl. pines; interfaz, pl.
>   interfaces; sij, pl. sijes. Son excepción las palabras esdrújulas, que
>   permanecen invariables en plural: polisíndeton, pl. (los)
>   polisíndeton; trávelin, pl. (los) trávelin; cáterin, pl. (los)
>   cáterin. Excepcionalmente, el plural de hipérbaton es hipérbatos.

Comment: I just wanted to add a link to the [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=sueter): **suéter** "Adaptación de la voz inglesa sweater, ‘prenda de punto y con mangas que cubre desde el cuello hasta la cintura’. Su plural es suéteres (→ plural, 1g): «Enfundado [...] en varios suéteres y chaquetas para protegerse del frío» (Glantz Rastro [Méx. 2002])."

Comment: It's essentially covered under the "rule" but I just wanted to make a note regarding the noun ending with a consonant.  Keep in mind that a gender change (e.g. profesor -> profesora) will change how you create a plural (e.g. profesores -> profesoras).

Comment: @McArthey technically, the gender change happens first (you go from profesor to profesora to profesoras)

Answer (score 1):

If they do not precede the other consonant, form the plural with -es. And example is "dócil"; it becomes "dóciles". However, words such as "bufanda" (scarf), end with a vowel. In this case, you can simply just add an "s" at the end.